# query to get sheet names in excel (java)

Tags: java, excel, spring, database, spring-boot

I am trying to get the list of sheet names present in the excel file. Is there any query to get the sheet names? I am using

```
Class.forName("com.hxtt.sql.excel.ExcelDriver").newInstance();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of Apache's POI Library for that. [More help here on how to do it with example](http://obscuredclarity.blogspot.in/2011/12/get-sheet-names-from-excel-file-using.html)

Alternatively, you can use the JXL library and use the following code :

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import jxl.Workbook;
import jxl.read.biff.BiffException;

public class GetSheetNamesTest {

  /**
   * @param args
   * @throws IOException 
   * @throws BiffException 
   */
  public static void main(String[] args) throws BiffException, IOException {
    //Read the given XL sheet 
    Workbook workbook = Workbook.getWorkbook(new File("C:/JXL/Sheet-Names.xls"));
    System.out.println("Number of sheets in this workbook : " + workbook.getNumberOfSheets());

    String [] sheetNames = workbook.getSheetNames();

    for (int i = 0 ; i < sheetNames.length ; i ++ ) {
      System.out.println("Sheet Name[" + i + "] = " + sheetNames[i]);
    }

    //Close and free allocated memory 
    workbook.close(); 
  }

}
```

Comment: Is there any option without going for POI. I am in need of a query.

Comment: getSheetName(int sheet)
Get the sheet name

workbook.getSheetNames(); does not exist anymore:-)

Answer (score 0):

For Springboot, we can use getNumberOfSheets() and getSheetAt() functions of POI library.

Example code below:

```
  public static ArrayList<String> getSheetNames(InputStream is) {
      ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
        try {
            Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(is);
            for(int i = 0; i< workbook.getNumberOfSheets(); i++) {
                Sheet firstSheet = workbook.getSheetAt(i);
                names.add(firstSheet.getSheetName());   
            }
            workbook.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
              throw new RuntimeException("fail to parse Excel file: " + e.getMessage());
            }
      return names;
  }
```

Calling function:

```
List<String> listName = ExcelHelper2.getSheetNames(file.getInputStream());
```